# Need help in MySql query INSERT IF NOT EXISTS Otherwise UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, c#-4.0

I need you small help, I would like to update the existing record, If it already exists in table otherwise Insert the new record. I am not using the primary key column in the `Where` clause.

Every time Its insert the new record in the table with the same column 1 and column 2 values.

I have got the few response as well like use the REPLACE. But REPLACE will work for the case of Unique / Primary Key otherwise inserted the new record.

I have used the below query

Method 1:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from mytable3 WHERE field1 = 'A') THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable3  
    SET (field1 ='A', field2 = 'DD')  
    WHERE field1 = 'A'  
END
ELSE   
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  mytable3 (field1, field2) VALUES ('A', 'DD')
END
```

Method 2:

```
REPLACE mytable3 (field1, field2) VALUES ('A', 'DD');
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable3 
(
     users int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     field1 varchar(10), 
     field2 varchar(10), 
     PRIMARY KEY(users)
); 

insert into mytable3 (field1, field2) values('A', 'AA');
insert into mytable3 (field1, field2) values('B', 'BB');
insert into mytable3 (field1, field2) values('C', 'CC');
```

**Note**: every time Its insert the new record in the table with the same field 1 and field 2 values

-------------------------  Original Question ------------------

I'm struggling to write MySql query to insert new records if not exists, otherwise Update the existing record. But I am facing the Syntax error as below:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wnduty.`parcel-status-log`
>   WHERE `parcel-id` = 1 AND `sh' at line 1

The SQl Query as below:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wnduty.`parcel-status-log` WHERE `parcel-id` = 1 AND `shipping-status-id` = 4) 
   THEN 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE wnduty.`parcel-status-log`  SET (`status-date` ='2016-06-10 10:41:58', `is-synced`= 3) 
            WHERE `parcel-id` = 1 AND `shipping-status-id` = 4
        END        
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO wnduty.`parcel-status-log`  (`parcel-id`,`shipping-status-id`, `is-synced`,`status-date`) 
            values(1, 4, 1, '2016-06-10 10:41:58') 
        END 
END IF
```

I have also try by below query but still syntax error..

```
INSERT INTO wnduty.`parcel-status-log` (`parcel-id`, `shipping-status-id`, `is-synced`, `status-date`) values(1, 4, 1, '2016-06-10 10:41:57')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`status-date` ='2016-06-13 11:41:58',`is-synced` = 3, `shipping-status-id` = 4 ;
```

**I am using the MySql version as below:**

- innodb_version   5.7.12
- protocol_version 10
- version_compile_os   Win64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: may be you cannot have -

Comment: Every time its Inserting the new record insted of Update the existing one.

Problem Not Resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can use UPDATE INTO with the same syntax as INSERT INTO and if the record is a duplicate on any of the unique keys in the table then it will update the record, otherwise it will insert using the same SQL statement.

Comment: Still getting the error near IF EXISTS as below

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT *

Comment: Actually System Error shoing at IF location at start. when I mose rollover the error as below

'IF' (if) is not valid input at this position

Answer (score 0):

Just use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) instead of INSERT, it does exactly what you are looking for ...

`INSERT INTO wnduty.parcel-status-log ...`

`REPLACE wnduty.parcel-status-log ...`

From mysql man :

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 14.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

Full REPLACE example :

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable ( users TINYINT(1), field varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY(users));
mysql> insert into mytable values(1, 'A');
mysql> insert into mytable values(2, 'B');
mysql> insert into mytable values(3, 'C');
```

Now Replace a row with a new value no matter if it exists or not :

```
mysql> REPLACE mytable (users, field) VALUES (2, "New Value");
mysql> REPLACE mytable (users, field) VALUES (4, "D");
```

Comment: I have tried by replace  but still the same error

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wnduty.`parcel-status-log` WHERE `parcel-id` = 1 AND `shipping-status-id` = 4) 
   THEN 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE wnduty.`parcel-status-log`  SET (`status-date` ='2016-06-10 10:41:58', `is-synced`= 3) 
            WHERE `parcel-id` = 1 AND `shipping-status-id` = 4
        END        
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            REPLACE  wnduty.`parcel-status-log`  (`parcel-id`,`shipping-status-id`, `is-synced`,`status-date`) 
            values(1, 4, 1, '2016-06-10 10:41:58') 
        END 
END IF

Comment: Actually System Error shoing at IF location at start. when I mose rollover the error as below 'IF' (if) is not valid input at this position

Comment: Pls HELP by below example
       
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
  users  varchar(10),
  field  varchar(10)
);

--

insert into mytable
values('abc', 'hdgsh');

insert into mytable
values('abdc', 'hdsagsh');

insert into mytable
values('abcd', 'hdgshfg');

insert into mytable
values('something', 'hdgshfg');       
       
select * from mytable 
       
 
-- I need the below query 

IF EXISTS (select * from mytable where users = 'something') then
    select field from mytable where users = 'something' END IF;
    
else
    REPLACE   mytable (users) values ('something2');

Comment: Dear Sir Its working fine when update with the Primary Key field or all the fileds have matched with existing record. If the update critaria without primary Key filed (example just one field in where clause and we have to update all the matched fields) then It always insert the new record.

I need to update witout Key field.